# Infinity loops with useEffect and useCallback - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

somehow I got an infinity loop, the weird situation that I did solve it but I got a warning and I wish to fix the warning.

this is code that work:

```
import { ArrowDropDown, ArrowRight } from "@material-ui/icons";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import "./tree.css";

const Tree = ({ explorer }) => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(true);
  const [arrow, setArrow] = useState(false);

  const stateHandler = () => {
    setExpand(!expand);
    setArrow(!arrow);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //this function will display only the first Tree as init the page.
    stateHandler();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="treeInfo">
        {arrow ? (
          <ArrowDropDown className="treeIcon" />
        ) : (
          <ArrowRight className="treeIcon" />
        )}

        <span className="treeTitle" onClick={stateHandler}>
          {explorer.name}
        </span>
      </div>

      <div
        style={{
          display: expand ? "block" : "none",
          paddingLeft: 20,
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
      >
        {explorer.items.map((explore) => {
          return <Tree key={explore.id} explorer={explore} />;
        })}
        {/* {explorer.items.map((explore) => (
          <Tree explorer={explore} />
        ))} */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tree;
```

and this is the warning:

```
src\components\Tree\Tree.js
  Line 17:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'stateHandler'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in src\components\Tree\Tree.js
  Line 17:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'stateHandler'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

**

- The result  : (it's good its what I want to display a tree view of
  files)

**

[image: result]

well as I can read I got this warning because useEffect got not dependencies, when I add the stateHandler dependencies I got an infinity loop, so I add a callback function but it still doesn't solve the infinity loop.
this is the code with the useCallback (its the same code, just with useCallback and a bit of configure of the useEffect):

```
 const initTree = useCallback(() => {
    setExpand(!expand);
    setArrow(!arrow);
  }, [setExpand, setArrow, arrow, expand]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //this function will display only the first Tree as init the page.
    initTree();
  }, [initTree]);
```

Comment: well the infinite loop is because when `initTree` runs, `expand` and `arrow` are updated, which mean the `initTree` callback is changed so the effect runs again and `initTree` is called... You could avoid this by using the callback versions of the "set" functions: `setExpand(expand => !expand)` and so on - but the simplest solution is to not bother with the `useEffect` and just set the initial `expand` and `arrow` to the opposites of what you are currently setting them to. Why do you need them to suddenty flip in valud just once after initial render??

Comment: @RobinZigmond You are right! I remove all the useEffect and Callback and just just the state to false and everything worked :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to change this:

```
 const initTree = useCallback(() => {
    setExpand(!expand);
    setArrow(!arrow);
  }, [setExpand, setArrow, arrow, expand]);
```

to this:

```
 const initTree = useCallback(() => {
    setExpand(e => !e);
    setArrow(a => !a);
  }, []);
```

Otherwise what happens is this:

1. The component renders, `initTree` variable is initialized with a function, the `Effect` is run and `setExpand` and `setArrow` are called.
2. That triggers a new render
3. The `useCallback` hook checks if the deps of `initTree` have changed and yes, `arrow` and `expand` have changed indeed, hence `initTree` variable is updated with a new function
4. The effect checks if `initTree` has changed from the previous render, and yes, it has changed, hence the effect executes again calling `initTree` again.
5. There you are stuck in an infinite render loop.

Eslint shouldn't complain of missing deps if you don't put the `setState` in deps, since they do not change during renders, unless you are passing them through props.

Comment: this is the "solution" I suggested in my comment that I was typing when your answer appeared, but I don't understand why any of this is needed rather than just initialising `expand` and `arrow` to the opposites of what the OP is currently setting them to, thereby avoiding needing any `useEffect`.

Comment: I tried to answer to OP's question title, to be a good reference for future readers. I'm not questioning his code, which seems deifnitely weird, and doesn't make much sense.

Comment: its work, but I still got the warning : "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initTree'" how can I avoid it?

Comment: You should place `initTree` in the useEffect deps array now, it won't create problems, since it won't change after the first render.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with having another state, you can simply set something like a `loading` state and make the useEffect depend on that

State would look like this:

```
const [expand, setExpand] = useState(true);
const [arrow, setArrow] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

And then based on this, useEffect would change as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //this function will display only the first Tree as init the page.
    stateHandler();
    setLoading(false);
}, [loading]);
```

Once loading is set to false, it's value is not going to change and the useEffect will not be triggered indefinitely

Comment: But I still got the warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'stateHandler if i do add this dependency I got the infinity loop